# browser.wait ignores my parameter to wait 20 seconds Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I have written this test, however browser doesn't wait those 20 seconds before looking for an element. It ignores that part and only wait those default 11 seconds.  Is there something wrong with my code?

```
it('should navigate to Home tab', function() {
    element(by.css('[ui-sref="main.home"]')).click();

    var telematicsSection = element(by.id('teleMap'));

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(telematicsSection), 20000);
});
```

This is an error I get

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>   While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="teleMap"]).

**@edit**

I've managed to fix it. Yash Jagdale's code and

> allScriptsTimeout: 20000

in conf.js made it work.

Comment: In your config file, what value do you have set for `allScriptsTimeout`?

Comment: Have you read through the link given?

Comment: As Gunderson pointed out, it is likely an issue with your declaration of timeouts. Can you show us your conf.js code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way to handle async cycle properly

```
    it('should navigate to Home tab', function(callback) {
        element(by.css('[ui-sref="main.home"]')).click().then(function() {

        var telematicsSection = element(by.id('teleMap'));

        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(telematicsSection), 20000).then(function() {
           callback();
         });
      });
    }, 40000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately same result

Comment: allScriptsTimeout: 20000 in conf.js and your bit of code resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in `onPrepare` of protractor conf.js

```
onPrepare: function() {

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be useful to not ignore synchronization in any other cases but just not this one. ignoreSynchronization will affect all of my tests.